# Exception handling of coroutines in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, cancellation

I created a script that changes the transparency of the GameObject it's attached to and I do the transparency change in a fading coroutine which needs to be cancellable (and canceled everytime we call `ChangeTransparency()` with a new value). I managed to get it working the way I want it but I want to handle the `OperationCanceledException` that is flooding my Console. I know that you **cannot** wrap a `yield return` statement inside a `try-catch` block.

**What is a proper way to handle Exceptions inside Unity coroutines?**

Here is my script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class Seethrough : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isTransparent = false;
    private Renderer componentRenderer;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private const string materialTransparencyProperty = "_Fade";


    private void Start()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        componentRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    public void ChangeTransparency(bool transparent)
    {
        //Avoid to set the same transparency twice
        if (this.isTransparent == transparent) return;

        //Set the new configuration
        this.isTransparent = transparent;

        cts?.Cancel();
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        if (transparent)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeTransparency(0.4f, 0.6f, cts.Token));
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeTransparency(1f, 0.5f, cts.Token));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator FadeTransparency(float targetValue, float duration, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Material[] materials = componentRenderer.materials;
        foreach (Material material in materials)
        {
            float startValue = material.GetFloat(materialTransparencyProperty);
            float time = 0;

            while (time < duration)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();  // I would like to handle this exception somehow while still canceling the coroutine

                material.SetFloat(materialTransparencyProperty, Mathf.Lerp(startValue, targetValue, time / duration));
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }

            material.SetFloat(materialTransparencyProperty, targetValue);
        }
    }
}
```

My temporary solution was to check for the token's cancellation flag and break out of the while loop. While it solved this current problem, I am still in need of a way to handle these exceptions that are thrown in asynchronous methods (coroutines) in Unity.

Comment: why dont you just stop the previous corroutine on the new `ChangeTransparency` call?

Comment: What exception do you see when you replace `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequest()` with  `if (token.IsCancellationRequested){ yield break; }`? What "asynchronous exceptions" are you getting?

Comment: I edited my last sentence. I was reffering to the exceptions thrown from in asynchronously running methods (coroutines). I don't get any exceptions when checking for the token's cancel flag, but I still want to be able to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358869/7111561) is good and all but actually not really on point for the use case you are trying to solve.

You don't have any async code but need the code to be executed in the Unity main thread since it is using Unity API and most of it can only be used on the main thread.

A [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) is **NOT ASYNC** and has nothing todo with multithreading or Tasks!

A Coroutine is basically just an `IEnumerator` as soon as it is registered as a Coroutine by `StartCorotuine` then Unity calls `MoveNext` on it (which will execute everything until the next `yield return` statement) right after `Update` so once a frame (there are some special yield statements like `WaitForFixedUpdate` etc which are handled in different message stacks but still) on the Unity main thread.

So e.g.

```
// Tells Unity to "pause" the routine here, render this frame
// and continue from here in the next frame
yield return null;
```

or

```
// Will once a frame check if the provided time in seconds has already exceeded
// if so continues in the next frame, if not checks again in the next frame
yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
```

If you really need to somehow react to the cancelation within the routine itself there speaks nothing against your approach except, instead of immediately throw an exception rather only check the  [`CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested#System_Threading_CancellationToken_IsCancellationRequested) and react to it like

```
while (time < duration)
{
    if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Handle the cancelation

        // exits the Coroutine / IEnumerator regardless of how deep it is nested in loops
        // not to confuse with only "break" which would only exit the while loop
        yield break;
    }
            
    ....
```

---

To answer also on your title. It is true you can't do `yield return` inside a `try - catch` block and as said in general there isn't really a reason to do so anyway.

If you really need to you can wrap some parts of your code without the `yield return` in a `try - catch` block and in the `catch` you do your error handling and there you can again `yield break`.

```
private IEnumerator SomeRoutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            if(Random.Range(0, 10) == 9) throw new Exception ("Plop!");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
            yield break;
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a coroutine not being async? Is the method inside a coroutine actually executed on the main thread while the enumerator pattern's yield return takes care of the execution state?

Comment: Oh, I see that you just edited the answer and added a link to Unity docs. Thanks!

Comment: @Zserbinator a Coroutine is basically just an `IEnumerator` as soon as it is registered as a Coroutine by `StartCorotuine` then Unity calls `MoveNext` on it (which will execute everything until the next `yield return` statement) right after `Update` so once a frame (there are some special yield statements like `WaitForFixedUpdate` etc which are handled in different message stacks but still) on the Unity main thread

Comment: @MickyD well it is **the** way to implement a Coroutine in Unity. That is what OP is asking about. Some random developers **opinion** (the arguments there are quite questionable) on `IEnumerator` (btw not `IEnumerable`) doesn't really count. A Coroutine **is not** and is also **not intended** to replace **asynchronous** code! A Coroutine is exited until the next `yield return` within one frame on the Unity main thread which is essential to be able to interact with Unity API that is not multithreading ready!

Comment: @MickyD As said `make a simple frame-updated-time-based interpolator function` is exactly what Coroutines in Unity are used for. They basically are small temporary `Update` methods if you want so but they can be turned on and off and don't need to rely on external class fields but can store local variables that are sure not be changed / accesible by anything else.

Comment: @MickyD which are these two? Because as said using asynchronous code for doing these things will not be possible at all .. and also as said using the `Update` method is not really a replacement either, requires additional fields, and can't be turned off while not needed so it is less efficient. Also options mentioned in your link like `Invoke` etc make no sense for this use case either .. not sure how this is related to `DoEvents` at all

Comment: @MickyD the latter link is from the Microsoft documentation .. and simply nonsense .. refer to the Unity documentation. Coroutines are not async. The formulation from that Microsoft doc is completely misleading .. the purpose of Coroutines is exciting a certain thing over multiple frames .. one thing where it is used for asynchronous stuff (and that's the only way) is waiting on the main thread by `yield return` every frame until a certain condition (e.g. the task is finished) is fulfilled and then do other things .. still on the main thread without having to dispatch the task result back

Answer (score 2):

---

This answer is an example of *[“don’t do that...try this instead”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*.

---

**EDIT:** If you don't want to use `Task`s and aren't too sure about coroutines, why not use a simple time-based interpolation function in each frame update.  It's a cleaner version of what coroutines are trying to do.

---

Coroutines in Unity provide an easy way to perform a *lengthy operation over a series of frames* however they are not without their problems.  One of which is the heated debate over their apparent odd use of `IEnumerator` from the C# communality as a whole (search this site). But alas I digress.

### Alternatives to coroutines?

Why not just use `async/await`?  Ever since *Unity 2018.1*, Unity has had **full support** for **.NET 4.5+** and with it the *Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)*.  Once you do you will find that things become easier, you open yourself up to a much wider of code samples and you dodge that pesky `IEnumerator` debate.

MSDN:

> In Unity, asynchronous programming is typically accomplished with coroutines. However, since C# 5, the preferred method of asynchronous programming in .NET development has been the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) using the async and await keywords with System.Threading.Task. In summary, in an async function you can await a task's completion without blocking the rest of your application from updating... [More...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/unity-scripting-upgrade)

Sample courtesy MSDN:

```
// .NET 4.x async-await
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class AsyncAwaitExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    private async void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Wait.");
        await WaitOneSecondAsync();
        DoMoreStuff(); // Will not execute until WaitOneSecond has completed
    }
    private async Task WaitOneSecondAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Debug.Log("Finished waiting.");
    }
}
```

### Exception handling

> Cancel coroutine operations in Unity 
> What is a proper way to handle Exceptions inside Unity coroutines?

So this is one of the first problems with coroutines.

The answer is not to use coroutines at all (assuming you are running Unity 2018.1+) and start to migrate to `async/await`.  Then exception handling can be performed such as:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class AsyncAwaitExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    private async void Start()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource ();
        Debug.Log("Wait.");

        try
        {
            await DoSomethingRisky(cts.Token);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Terribly sorry but something bad happened");
        }

        DoMoreStuff(); // Will not execute until DoSomethingRisky has completed/faulted
    }

    private async Task DoSomethingRisky()
    {
        // ...something risky here

        throw new ApplicationException("Ouch!");
    }
}
```

Now to handle specic cases such as Task cancellation you would:

```
public class AsyncAwaitExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts;

    private async void Start()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource ();
        Debug.Log("Wait.");

        try
        {
            await PerformLengthyOperationAsync(cts.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex) 
        {
            // task was cancelled
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Terribly sorry but something bad happened");
        }
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        try
        {
            if (someCondition)
               cts.Cancel();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex) 
        {
            // Yup I know, I cancelled it above
        }
    }

    private async Task PerformLengthyOperationAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var ok = true;

        do
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ();

            // continue to do something lengthy...
            // ok = still-more-work-to-do?
        }
        while (ok);
    }
}
```

### See also

- [*Using .NET 4.x in Unity*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/unity-scripting-upgrade), MSFT
- [*.NET profile support*](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html), Unity
- Arnott, A, [Recommended patterns for CancellationToken](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/), DevBlogs, Microsoft

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I did not know that Unity supports the TAP library.

Comment: That's a very extended answer! However, in OP's original use case I would say a Coroutine is indeed absolutely what you want to go with! OPs code is supposed to be executed once a frame in the Unity main thread and nothing about asynchronous at all!

Comment: @derHugo OP's question is about _"Exception handling of coroutines in Unity"_ - which is the 2nd part of my answer.  Whether or not the OP is performing _interpolation_ is incidental.

Comment: @Zserbinator if you don't want to use `Task`  then try to ween yourself away from coroutines.  All my time-based, frame-updated interpolation functions are just that - a function.  No need for `Task`s either.   The vast majority of coroutine code I see can be done without it. See my update to question

Comment: @MickyD `time-based interpolation function in each frame update` is exactly what happens in a Coroutine just that it happens only then when really needed and the coroutine is running. And `Exception handling of coroutines in Unity` is the title, yes .. an example of an XY problem. But from the code and description you see pretty well what OP actually is trying to achieve: End the Coroutine in the moment the token is cancelled and optionally some reaction before that. It's not about the interpolation but rather the fact that `Material.SetFloat` can only be done in the main thread

Comment: And as explained `async/await` is **not** an alternative to Coroutines! Coroutines never are async ..