# Exception handling with unity Coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script named `LocationService` that is responsible to Start the Unity location service.
The script has a coroutine that handles starting the service and invokes an `Action` when it's done.

So far so good, the problem is that if for some reason the service doesn't start
maybe the user doesn't give access, in that case, I throw an exception with the necessary info so I can handle that on the class that called the Method to start the service, which is responsible to interact with the user.

Of course, I can just show some message to the user directly from the `LocationService` or call a method that does that, but that will break the **Single responsibility**.

So the question is Is there any workaround to handle exceptions that are thrown in a coroutine?

The `LocationService` Looks like

```
public void RequireLocation()
{
    StopAllCoroutines();
    StartCoroutine(LocationCoroutine());
}

private IEnumerator LocationCoroutine()
{
    //...
    throw new LocationException("Unable to determine device location, Permission Denied!");
}
```

The `RequireLocation` gets called from a class that handles the user interactions and it would look something like this

```
var locationService //...
try
{
   locationService.RequireLocation()
}
catch(LocationException ex)
{
   //showing a message
}
```

Comment: We use callbacks for this, either a single one with a status parameter or onSuccess/onFailure.

Comment: Hmm... will try that. do you have any references, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception handling of coroutines in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355725/exception-handling-of-coroutines-in-unity), specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358869/585968) answer.

Comment: Also, take not of _[Why innocent-looking coroutines are actually dangerous](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2022/10/06/implementing-time-based-delays-in-unity-3d/)_.  From earlier today, [an example of a coroutine gone astray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74585481/unity-physics-overlapsphere-accessing-objects-that-have-already-been-destroyed).

Comment: Thank you for all the documentation you provided to me, I really appreciate it, and I was able to make it work by using async await instead of Coroutines.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355725/exception-handling-of-coroutines-in-unity/70358869#70358869